# Ember : downgrading ember with bower install

Tags: ember.js, bower, bower-install

I've been switching to the 1.13.2 version of ember on a git branch, and now I want to come back to 1.11.1 when going back to an other branch.

I've been running `npm install` and `bower install` without failure.

But when I run `ember server` I run into the following error :

```
Missing bower packages: 
Package: ember
  * Specified: 1.11.1
  * Installed: 1.13.2

Run `bower install` to install missing dependencies.
```

Running `bower install` again does not solve the problem, neither does `bower cache clean`.

Comment: That was it, quick. Post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do

```
$ rm -rf bower_components
$ bower cache clean
$ bower install
```