# ember error "Specified 2.3.0 Installed 2.4.3" on "ember s"

Tags: ember.js, bower

Somehow I've stuffed up my, previously working, ember.js environment.

When I try to start the server I get:

```
glaucon@polo ~/dev/ember-django-testbed $ ember s

Missing bower packages:
Package: ember
  * Specified: 2.3.0
  * Installed: 2.4.3

Run `bower install` to install missing dependencies.
```

If I do then run `bower install` I get this

```
glaucon@polo ~/dev/ember-django-testbed $ bower install ember --save-dev
bower ember#*                   cached git://github.com/components/ember.git#2.4.3
bower ember#*                 validate 2.4.3 against git://github.com/components/ember.git#*
bower ember#>=1.4               cached git://github.com/components/ember.git#2.4.3
bower ember#>=1.4             validate 2.4.3 against git://github.com/components/ember.git#>=1.4
```

But after doing that I am still left with the previous error message when I try to do `ember s`

I then (as per [Running "ember server" fails with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775053/running-ember-server-fails-with-error)) tried this

```
$ bower cache clean
```

followed by:

```
$ bower install ember --save-dev
```

But still the same error message:

Just to be sure I then followed the advice of https://stackoverflow.com/a/31167757/364088 and did the following :

```
$ rm -rf bower_components
$ bower cache clean
$ bower install
```

And .. still the same error message!

---

EDIT

Forgot to put this bit in. This is `bower.json`

```
glaucon@polo ~/dev/ember-django-testbed $ cat bower.json
{
  "name": "ember-django-testbed",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "2.3.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.2",
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.1.7",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "jquery": "1.11.3",
    "loader.js": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "ember": "^2.4.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ember": "^2.4.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bower.json, change:

```
"ember": "2.3.0"
```

To:

```
"ember": "^2.4.3"
```

After that delete bower components map and run:

```
bower install
```

Comment: Thanks, just what was needed.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the line in `bower.json` `dependencies` from

```
"ember": "2.3.0"
```

to

```
"ember": "^2.4.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Source: [How to update your Ember.js project?](http://yoember.com/emberjs/how-to-keep-your-ember-js-project-up-to-date/)

When you upgrade your Ember app, consider using the following steps.

#### Upgrade ember-cli

outside your older ember app

```
$ cd ~
$ npm install -g ember-cli
```

Check your ember-cli version (outside of your project folder).

```
$ cd ~
$ ember -v
```

You should see the latest version.

#### Create a totally new ember application

to see, the packages in `bower.json` and `package.json`. (For example, if you have a projects folder, and you have a temp folder for short term stuffs.) You can use the version number in the app name, so you can check it later.

```
$ cd ~/projects/temp
$ ember new my-v24-app
```

This dummy app is always a good cornerstone for checking the compatible versions.

#### Upgrade version numbers in your old project to match with the new dummy app.

Check your `bower.json` and `package.json` align the version numbers in your old project to match with the new defaults. (Update ember-cli, ember, ember-data, etc.) It is time to double check your other packages, like sass or firebase, etc. packages also, maybe there are an updated version which is compatible with the new Ember.

#### Remove `bower_components` and `node_modules`

In most of the cases when you have some package conflict, the main reason is that an older and a newer version of package stay in your package/module folder. Yes, there are commands like `npm prune` and `bower prune` which clean package folders.

However, the most safest solution if you just remove these folders and reinstall all your packages.

```
$ cd my-updated-project
$ rm -rf bower_components node_modules
$ npm install && bower install
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: But in my case it shows `Missing bower packages: Package: ember  * Specified: 2.6.0  * Installed: 2.4.4`. Will you please tell me where to look for.

Comment: in your project folder, you can remove and recreate bower_components. `rm -rf bower_components` and after `bower install`

Comment: no It is not going to help!

Comment: What kind of operation system do you use? Windows/Linux/MacOSX, anyway, if you already have the new version in bower.json, and you delete the bower_packages folder, where previous versions are downloaded, it should work.